# Do I need an airside visa (or anything else) for transit via Heathrow from South Africa to Ireland?

Tags: visas, transit, lhr, ireland, south-african-citizens

I am traveling from South Africa on Virgin Atlantic to Heathrow airport where I change plane to Aer Lingus for the final leg if my journey to Dublin, Ireland. My bags are being checked through to the final destination. I will not need to go through immigration. My onward flight departs less than 2 hours after landing in Heathrow.

The purpose of my visit is to visit my son and his wife and family and to help care for twins born 16th January 2019.

I have valid SA passport, travel insurance, proof of foreign exchange, letter of invitation from my son (resident on a work permit in Kilkenny); no visa is required to visit Ireland on SA passport.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/republic_of_ireland

Comment: Also https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-visa-requirements-list-for-carriers/uk-visa-requirements-for-international-carriers

Comment: You _do_ need to go through immigration in Heathrow because the UK and the Republic of Ireland form a Common Travel Area. There will be no immigration control (other than possible spot checks) on arrival in Dublin. And for this you will need a UK Standard Visitor Visa. You would do better to change planes to Dublin in an EU airport (or some others) where you do not need a visa, as you can stay airside.

Comment: You need a entry visa in the UK as airside transit is not available for onward flights within the Common Travel Area. There are systematic passport checks for all arrivals at Dublin Airport irrespective of origin. You would be far better off avoiding the UK altogether, by transiting though a Schengen airport.